# Word in one table cell bigger than another?

Tags: html, html-table

I've got a strange problem. When I watch my Dutch minisite on my own computer (1920x1080), everything looks fine. But when I check it on another computer with a 1152x864 resolution, the word in the leftmost cell is significantly bigger than the other ones (see the attached picture), while they are all H2, as you can see in the code below.

Does anybody know how to fix this? That would be much appreciated.

P.S. I've set the borders to 1, as that enables us to see the difference better.

[Link to the website](http://smc.webege.com/vraag.php)
[image: Website on a 1152x864 resolution]

```
<tr align='center'>
<h2>
<td width='25%' style='word-wrap: break-word;'>Onderwerp</td>
<td width='25%' style='word-wrap: break-word;'>Lijdend voorwerp</td>
<td width='25%' style='word-wrap: break-word;'>Meewerkend voorwerp</td>
<td width='25%' style='word-wrap: break-word;'>Bezittelijk voornaamwoord</td>
</h2>
</tr>
```

Comment: maybe it is because u're using percentage instead of pt or px, once the text is bigger than one sentence it auto sizes?!

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid, odd results are to be expected. `<tr>` can only have `<td>` or `<th>` as direct child elements.

You could try:

```
<tr align='center'>
<td width='25%' style='word-wrap: break-word;'><h2>Onderwerp</h2></td>
<td width='25%' style='word-wrap: break-word;'><h2>Lijdend voorwerp</h2></td>
<td width='25%' style='word-wrap: break-word;'><h2>Meewerkend voorwerp</h2></td>
<td width='25%' style='word-wrap: break-word;'><h2>Bezittelijk voornaamwoord</h2></td>
</tr>
```